# Download one html page with all needed graphics and linked pdf/zip files

Tags: wget, web, download

I want to download a website from an URL, to view it locally, more exactly:

- Download *one single* html page (no other linked html pages) and everything needed to display it (css, images, etc.)
- Also download all directly linked files of type `pdf` and `zip`.
- And correct all links to them, so the links do work locally.
- The other links (for example to html files) should be kept untouched.

I'm open to all linux-based tools (`macports` support would be nice), using `wget` didn't work out for me so far.

**Edit:** `wget -E -H -k -K -p` is close to what I want, but how do I include pdf and zip files?
(Source:  [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780601/wget-span-host-only-for-images-stylesheets-javascript-but-not-links))

Comment: What did you try with `wget`?

Comment: I added my best attempt as an edit.

Answer (score 3):

[HTTrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httrack) ([homepage](http://www.httrack.com/)) can mirror sites for off-line viewing with a rather fine grained options as to what to download and what not. It is also able to resume interrupted downloads.

Comment: I'm also suggesting HTTrack. Used it on Windows and it really works

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
wget -r -k -l 1 --mirror yourSITE
```

Reason of `-r` along with `--mirror`:

`-r`:  cuased `wget` acts recursively.

`--mirror`: cuased you tell wget behave such as mirror sites.Sometimes It needed.

`-k`  : single documentation

`-l 1` : level 1, one level recursively.

Comment: Tried that, but the level restriction isn't working. It basically mirrors the whole site.

Comment: From the wget documentation:
`‘--mirror’
Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps ftp directory listings. It is currently equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.`

It seems `-l 1 --mirror` overrides `-l 1` with `-l inf`.

See my answer omitting the --mirror option.

Comment: better readeable explanation: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-r+-k+-l+1+--mirror+yourSITE

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `wget -rk -l 1 <sitename>` or similar?  That should recursively fetch the content while converting the links to relative paths.  The end result may be more .html files than you want, but you can remove all of them except for index.html which you should be able to browse normally.

Comment: `-m,--mirror` is also an interesting option.

Comment: mirror is not suitable.  OP suggests he only wants the first level.  Mirroring the site sets unrestricted recursion.

Comment: Looks good, but linked css files generated by php scripts (for example `css-style.php?option1=bla`) don't work. I couldn't figure out how to get them working yet.

Comment: Right, that is to be somewhat expected.  There are some dynamic pieces of content that wget may not fetch or that may be fetched in a static manner.  Also, I think some static content like `<link>` specified content may not be fetched.

I haven't used the other product suggested (HTTRack).  Does it do a better job?